# Highcharts donut pie not showing hover indicator if the slice color is white

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm having this issue due to white slice of the donut. You'll get more idea after seeing my code and screenshots below:

So here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    colors: ['#00aeef', '#7FD6F7', '#ffffff'],
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      floating: true,
      text: 'CENTERED<br>TEXT'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        innerSize: '80%'
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [
        {name:'Firefox', y:30},
        {name:'IE7', y:35},
        {name:'IE6', y:35, borderColor: '#00aeef'}
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

And here how the donut looks after that

[image]

so if I hover on one of the slices then it looks something like this

[image]

also checkout what happens when I hover on the slice of white color

[image]

I think it depends upon the color of the slice and chooses the lighter version of it as it's hover indicator but the problem is that there is nothing in the docs to tweak this functionality.

Is there a way to tweak this functionality by setting the hover indicator color of our choice irrespective of the slice color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the `fill` attribute of the halo hover state ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1c30ruLo/)):

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        halo: {
          attributes: {
            fill: '#00aeef'
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.states.hover.halo.attributes) for more attribute opportunities.

This works on a `Series` level. To do it on a `Point` level you could try the below Highcharts extension (at your own risk) which allows setting a `haloColor` for the relevant points ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/519b2sju/2/)):

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'setState', function (proceed, state, move) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    if(state == 'hover' && this.series.halo && this.options.haloColor)
      this.series.halo.attr({ 'fill': this.options.haloColor });
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: This solution looks good and now a hover indicator is showing up on the white slice but the tool-tip link is still white which makes the hover indicator looks divided in two parts.

Comment: @Abhinav you can add `dataLabels: { connectorColor: '#00aeef' }` to your series. Like [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1fh7vqm3/). You can also do it inside the specific point, [if you like that better](https://jsfiddle.net/v32sgonz/).

Comment: I think this attributes: { fill: '#00aeef' } will set the same hover indicator color for all of the slices which will be a problem in case of a slice with different color instead of blue. Is there a way to keep the functionality as it is for the slices which aren't white or is there a way to set hover indicator color according to a particular slice color?

Comment: @Abhinav I'm not sure you can do that with options. I have a feeling it has to be for a series, and cannot be for a point. You can [this this mod](https://jsfiddle.net/519b2sju/2/) (with no warranty) that allows it by setting a `haloColor` for the relevant points.